# Can a Google Chrome Extension send a message from an extension webpage back to a website page and also reopen that page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension for ,my Bookmarks app.

A bookmark record has 4 images fields.

Each image filed has these options to set an image:

- Generate a screenshot of the viewport of the webpage
- select an image scraped from the webpage HTML
- Select a region of the webpage screen and then edit it with annotations

Orginally I had a modal style app that loaded in the popup.html file when the extension button was clicked in the toolbar.  Because I added the ability to select a region for the screenshot image though I now have to move that modal into the actual webpage DOM.

The reason is that when a user select to select a region screenshot from the modal, it has to close the modal/hide it and show the screen to make the selection.  On completion there is no way to re-open the popup from the menu bar!

So I am moving the modal to the webpage.  Clicking the toolbar button will then build and show the modal.  Then when user selects to select region for 1 of the 4 image fields, I will hide the modal and on completion I can simply show the hidden modal and populate a text input filed with the newly generated and uploaded image.

I am now trying to go a step further though.  After selecting the image region, instead of showing the Modal window right away.  I want to instead show the image in an editor style page which would be an HTML webpage that belonged to the extension (like this chrome-extension://mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg/fsCaptured.html).  It would open this in a new tab.

The user would then annotate with text, shapes, etc in the editor and then upload file.

This is where I am stuck.  When I get the URL back from the uploaded image, I need to then close this new tab window and go back to the main webpage that had the app modal window and where the screenshot selection was made from.  I would need to then open/show the modal again and fill in the text input for the new image upload field.

---

**So my question here is...**

Is it possibble for my extension to pass a message from my `chrome-extension://mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg/fsCaptured.html` page with the editor back to the webpage the modal is on?

I would need to:

1. Pass the image URL back to the webpage with a message
2. Close the extension editor page/tab
3. go back to/bring focus to the webpage with the modal on it

Is this even possibble?  I realize you can send messages from background scripts to content scripts and content scripts back to background scripts.

---

**UPDATE**

For the first part.  Perhaps the extension webpage would send a message to the `background.js` and then the `background.js` could send a message to the webpage content script.  This would solve that part of the process!

Would just need to figure out if the extension webpage can close itself and then bring focus to the original webpage?

**Update 2**

Looks like I figured it out.

You can make a tab selected/active with:

`chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});`

Answer (score 0):

I believe my custom extension page can send a message to the `background.js` 
and then the `background.js` could send a message to the webpage content script with the modal window and have it then update the image fields in that modal.

Next from my custom extension page I should be able to call `chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});` after it sends the above message to the content script which would then close the extension page and bring focus back to my webpage with the modal in it.